# How to get a list of character positions in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a function to sanitize unicode input in a web application, and I'm currently trying to reproduce the PHP function at the end of this page : http://www.iamcal.com/understanding-bidirectional-text/

I'm looking for an equivalent of PHP's preg_match_all in python. RE function findall returns matches without positions, and search only returns the first match. Is there any function that would return me every match, along with the associated position in the text ?

With a string `abcdefa` and the pattern `a|c`, I want to get something like `[('a',0),('c',2),('a',6)]`

Thanks :)

Comment: Beware: that code is matching against individual UTF-8 bytes, which is generally the wrong thing to do.  Convert to a Unicode string and compare against Unicode codepoints properly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this, but this was only a *printable* example. The final solution will use the regex `u'\u202A|\u202B|\u202D|\u202E'` for matching ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
text = 'abcdefa'
pattern = re.compile('a|c')
[(m.group(), m.start()) for m in pattern.finditer(text)]
```

Comment: +1 for such an elegant solution. Wish I could give more than just 1 upvote

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get `re.findall` to do this for you, but the following should work:

1. Use `re.findall` to find all the matching strings.
2. Use `str.index` to find the associate index of all strings returned by `re.findall`. **However, be careful when you do this:** if a string has two exact substrings in distinct locations, then `re.findall` will return both, but you'll need to tell `str.index` that you're looking for the second occurrence or the `nth` occurrence of a string. Otherwise, it will return an index that you already have. The best way I can think of to do this would be to maintain a dictionary that has the strings from the result of `re.findall` as keys and a list of indices as values

Hope this helps